# Link ( click on images open its details ) not working in any Mobiles

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-mobile, responsive-design, clickable

**Update :** Its My Customized Responsive Design Website.

On home page [website link](http://www.thefansworld.com/) there is sliding celebrity Images : on click of any celebrity it takes to it resp. pages  which is working on Desktop / laptop browser , i mean click - link working , but same if i open in  Any Cell Phones then `sliding images` is shown but `images` is `not click able` and it not going to resp. page of celebrity.

I am using `wp-roundabout-pro` ( https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-roundabout-pro/ )  plugin in my website ( `WordPress 3.8.4` )

i know the plugin is not support to current version of my word-press... but In Desktop / laptop browser all working prefect.

any idea what is the issue. please help me out... as if this issue is not short-out then my whole work will be wasted

**Below is plugin code :**

```
<?php

$anims = array('lazySusan', 'waterWheel', 'figure8', 'square', 'conveyorBeltLeft', 'conveyorBeltRight', 'diagonalRingLeft', 'diagonalRingRight', 'rollerCoaster', 'tearDrop', 'theJuggler', 'goodbyeCruelWorld');

if(!in_array($animation, $anims)){
$animation='conveyorBeltLeft';
$asclass = '';
} else {
$asclass = 'class="hideflow"';
}

$sid = 'rbt-'.uniqid();
$out = '<ul '.$asclass.' id="'.$sid.'">';

$fwidth = intval($data[opt1]);
$fheight = intval($data[opt2]);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
if($row[url]!='' && trim($row[url])!=' '){
 $img = '<img src="'.get_image_thumb($row[url], 'w='.$fwidth.'&h='.$fheight).'" />';
} else { 
 $img = '';
}

if($row[title]!='' && trim($row[title])!=' '){
//$ttlxz='<span class="rbt-title"><span>'.$row[title].'</span></span>';
 $ttlxz='';
} else {
 $ttlxz='';
}


if($row[desc]!='' && trim($row[desc])!=' '){
//$descxz='<span class="rbt-content"><span>'.$row[desc].'</span></span>';
 $descxz='';
} else {
 $descxz='';
}

$out = $out.'<li style="background-color:'.$row[color].'">'.$ttlxz.''.$descxz.'<a href='.$row[desc].'>'.$img.'</a></li>';
}

$out = $out.'</ul>
<style type="text/css">
#'.$sid.' {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
width: '.$data[opt5].'px;
height: '.$data[opt6].'px;
}

#'.$sid.' .roundabout-moveable-item {
height: '.$fheight.'px;
width: '.$fwidth.'px;
background-color: '.$data[opt4].';
text-align: left;
cursor: pointer;
overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("#'.$sid.'").roundabout({
autoplay: '.$data[opt7].',
autoplayDuration: '.$data[opt9].'000,
minOpacity: '.$data[opt10].',
maxOpacity: '.$data[opt11].',
reflect: '.$data[opt12].',
enableDrag: '.$data[opt13].',
dragAxis:"'.$data[opt3].'",
shape: "'.$animation.'",
autoplayPauseOnHover: '.$data[opt8].'
});
});
</script>
';

?>
```

Sample of HTML code generated  :

```
<div class="slider">
    <ul id="rbt-5428f4c10c934" class="hideflow roundabout-holder" style="padding: 0px; position: relative;">
    <li style="background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238); position: absolute; left: 684px; top: 58px; width: 137.19px; height: 82.314px; opacity: 0.19; z-index: 117; font-size: 6.4px;" class="roundabout-moveable-item">
    <a href="http://www.thefansworld.com/celebfanpage/shahrukh-khan/">
    <img src="http://www.thefansworld.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-roundabout-pro/cache/w=300&amp;h=180___Shahrukh-Khan-Magazine-Photoshoot.jpg">
    </a>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I taught my a link have some issue but my anchor link is seem to be perfect then why its not working in mobile phones.

Comment: It's working for me on mobile...

Comment: hey i check in Samsung grand in when i click on slider image of celebrity then from home page it takes me to inner pages but in inner page if i again link on it then its not working and vise versa ...

Comment: u got what .. i means some time it works on first attempt and if i click again on it then no click happens ... and some time totally not working ...

Comment: @mevius you there ? ... did u see it ?..any solution ?

Comment: any one facing same issue..please at-least let me know ..